# In outlook 2010, How do I trigger a macro when a new mail is recieved in a secondary mailbox?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have two mailboxes on my Outlook Profile and I need to perform a script whenever a new mail is recieved on my secondary mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with a piece of VB that runs in the background of your outlook to monitor your folder. Then from in the VB-code you could probably do whatever you want to happen.

First rightclick your ribbon, 'custimize the ribbon'.
There choose commands from 'All Tabs' and make sure you add the Developer one from the 'Main Tabs' to your ribbon.
Afterwards in your ribbon Developer-tab you can click on 'Visual Basic'
There in the overview you can see a Microsoft Outlook Object called 'ThisOutlookSession'.
Here we can put some code that will load when you start your outlook.

We'll create something basic to monitor a folder for incomming messages & how to handle them

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents SecondaryInbox As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set SecondaryInbox = Ns.Folders("Name of Secondary Inbox").Folders("Inbox").Items
    Set Ns = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub SecondaryInbox_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Do something on item add event..
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        ' ...
    End If
End Sub
```